rust early return from within an iterator
I am trying to write a function that takes in an input string and does some operation on it only if the string is alphanumeric, currently my code is:
    fn update(&mut self, input_string: String) -> bool {
        let chars = {
            let mut chars = Vec::new();
            for c in input_string.chars() {
                if !c.is_alphanumeric() {
                    return false
                } else {
                    chars.push(c);
                }
            }
            chars
        };
        // do something with chars 
        todo!()
    }

This does work, but I would prefer to do this with iterators rather than loops as I generally find the code cleaner and easier to work with. However, I can't find a way to early return from within an iterator e.g.
    fn update(&mut self, input_string: String) -> bool {
        let chars = input_string.chars().into_iter().map(|c| {
            if c.is_alphanumeric() {
                c
            } else {
                return false
            }
        });

        // do something with chars 
        todo!()
    } 

doesn't compile. How can I do an early return from within an iterator

Iterator trait provides a lot of cool methods for tackling this issue, one of them is Iterator::all, and you can you use it this way:
fn update(input: String) -> bool {
    if !input.chars().all(char::is_alphanumeric) {
        return false;
    }
    // do something with original input, it's still intact
    todo!()
}
// or ...
fn updatecool(input: String) -> Option<()> {
    // one liner :)
    input.chars().all(char::is_alphanumeric).then_some(())?;
    // do something with original input, it's still intact
    todo!()
}


all method will short circuit on first failed test and return early

Note that if OP needs to do something with the characters, this will pass over the string twice.

I'm not certain it is more readable than the explicit loop, but here is my attempt for an iterator-only version.
Some remarks:

since you plan to work on the vector of chars built by the function, I suppose you don't need to own the input string (except if you want to store it); a string-slice-reference (&str) is probably enough as the parameter,
we can allocate once for all instead of risking reallocations as the vector grows; the largest allocation occurs when all chars are alphanumeric and are made of a single byte in utf-8,
pushing the char before testing its class is not a problem since we will return false immediately without using chars,
if we absolutely want to make chars immutable, we can start the second part with let chars = chars.

fn with_iterator(input_string: &str) -> bool {
    let mut chars = Vec::with_capacity(input_string.len()); // worst case
    input_string.chars().all(|c| {
        chars.push(c);
        c.is_alphanumeric()
    }) && /* short-circuit */ {
        // do something with chars
        print!(" {:?}", chars);
        true
    }
}

fn explicit_loop(input_string: &str) -> bool {
    let chars = {
        let mut chars = Vec::new();
        for c in input_string.chars() {
            if !c.is_alphanumeric() {
                return false;
            } else {
                chars.push(c);
            }
        }
        chars
    };
    // do something with chars
    print!(" {:?}", chars);
    true
}

fn main() {
    for s in ["James", "Bond-007", "Bond007"] {
        println!("input_string {:?}", s);
        print!("• iter");
        println!(" {}", with_iterator(s));
        print!("• loop");
        println!(" {}", explicit_loop(s));
    }
}
/*
input_string "James"
• iter ['J', 'a', 'm', 'e', 's'] true
• loop ['J', 'a', 'm', 'e', 's'] true
input_string "Bond-007"
• iter false
• loop false
input_string "Bond007"
• iter ['B', 'o', 'n', 'd', '0', '0', '7'] true
• loop ['B', 'o', 'n', 'd', '0', '0', '7'] true
*/


If you want do the operation on chars, but stop it as soon as you get the first non-alphanumeric character consider using one of Iterator::try_* functions.
For example, Iterator::try_fold:
fn foo(input_string: &str) -> Option<Vec<char>> {
    input_string
        .chars()
        .try_fold(vec![], |mut chars, c| {
            if c.is_alphanumeric() {
                dbg!("alphanumeric", &c);
                chars.push(c);
                Some(chars)
            } else {
                dbg!("non-alphanumeric", &c);
                None
           }
        })
}

fn main() {
    dbg!(foo("Hello, world!"));
    dbg!(foo("Helloworld"));
}

Here we process the string char by char, but stop immediately on condition failure, returning None for non-alphanumeric strings and Some(...) for successful processing.
